# Learning vimscripting and functions

Tags: vimscript, functions

Can you help me how this function does what it does, like step by step?

```
function! GitBranch()
    return system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'")
endfunction
```

I previously used a [plugin](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim). Now I came across this function but can't understand it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function calls Vim's `system()` function. This passes its argument (a pipeline containing a git command) on to the shell and returns its output. See `help system()`.

I'm afraid explaining the way any given shell pipeline works isn't within the scope of this site. I'd recommend reading `man git-rev-parse` and `man tr` in your shell, or perhaps you could ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

To be honest, you don't really need to know in detail how the git command works. It returns your current branch: that's all you need to know!

Comment: I'm actually concerned about setting up a disruptive function in vimrc, that's all. Thank you for explaining it. I think it doesn't do anything more than fetching the git branch name, right?

Comment: My terminal  ([st](https://st.suckless.org)) cursor flickers in vim when this function is used, regardless whether it is a git directory or not. But when I use this [plugin](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch) the cursor doesn't flicker.Why is that?

Comment: @EnanAjmain the plugin does its work entirely inside Vim without using executing external commands, from what I can tell. Maybe you should run the [`system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function with `:silent`.

Comment: @EnanAjmain That's quite a different question from the one you asked here. You should maybe try asking a new question with more details about what you're doing: what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "when this function is used"? When/for how long does the flickering occur? etc.